# Likely deadlock to my request to payment provider

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, deadlock, swish

I have translated the code from an console project and seem to get a deadlock since the code doesnt send a request to the server, their logs show nothing. Nothing happens when i debug, its just waiting for something.

How do i alter this for web.forms or any other web based handler?

```
Public Function MakePaymentRequest(ByVal swishNumberToPay As String, ByVal amount As Decimal, ByVal message As String, ByVal instructionUUID As String) As PaymentRequestECommerceResponse
        Try
            Dim requestData = New PaymentRequestECommerceData() With {
                .payeePaymentReference = _payeePaymentReference,
                .callbackUrl = _callbackUrl,
                .payerAlias = swishNumberToPay,
                .payeeAlias = _merchantAlias,
                .amount = Math.Round(amount, 2).ToString().Replace(",", "."),
                .currency = "SEK",
                .message = message
            }

            Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler
            Dim client As New HttpClient

            PrepareHttpClientAndHandler(handler, client)

            Dim requestURL As String = URL.ProductionPaymentRequest & instructionUUID
            Dim mhttpMethod = HttpMethod.Put

            Select Case _environment
                Case "EMULATOR"
                    requestURL = URL.EmulatorPaymentRequest & instructionUUID
                Case "SANDBOX"
                    requestURL = URL.SandboxPaymentRequest
                    mhttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post
            End Select

            Dim httpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage With {
                .Method = mhttpMethod,
                .RequestUri = New Uri(requestURL),
                .Content = New StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            }

            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("host", httpRequestMessage.RequestUri.Host)

            Dim response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result <-- I cant get past here. Nothing happens at this step and i think its deadlocked.

            Dim errorMessage As String = String.Empty
            Dim location As String = String.Empty

            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim headers = response.Headers.ToList()

                If headers.Any(Function(x) x.Key = "Location") Then
                    location = response.Headers.GetValues("Location").FirstOrDefault()
                End If
            Else
                Dim readAsStringAsync = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                errorMessage = readAsStringAsync.Result
            End If

            client.Dispose()
            handler.Dispose()
            Return New PaymentRequestECommerceResponse() With {
        .[Error] = errorMessage,
        .Location = location
    }
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return New PaymentRequestECommerceResponse() With {
        .[Error] = ex.ToString(),
        .Location = ""
    }
        End Try
    End Function
```